# Play! war command - Is it possible to exclude certain jar from the application /lib folder

Tags: jboss, playframework

I'm trying to automate deployment of a play application as a .war file.

In the end the application will be run on JBOSS AS7. 
The problem I'm running into right now is that when I deploy the war to JBOSS I get this exception.

```
14:52:39,728 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting  deployment of "my-test-app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war"
14:52:43,822 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."my-test-app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.Start 
Exception in service jboss.deployment.unit."my-test-app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "my-test-app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:121) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759) [jboss-msc-1.0.1.GA.jar:1.0.1.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_22]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_22]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_22]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: Failed to parse POJO xml ["/C:/jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final/bin/content/my-test-app-server-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/netty-3.2.5.Final.jar/META-INF/jboss-beans.xml"]
    at org.jboss.as.pojo.KernelDeploymentParsingProcessor.parseDescriptor(KernelDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:130)
    at org.jboss.as.pojo.KernelDeploymentParsingProcessor.parseDescriptors(KernelDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:104)
    at org.jboss.as.pojo.KernelDeploymentParsingProcessor.deploy(KernelDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:115) [jboss-as-server-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[17,1] Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0}deployment'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:98) [staxmapper-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:59) [staxmapper-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.pojo.KernelDeploymentParsingProcessor.parseDescriptor(KernelDeploymentParsingProcessor.java:123)
    ... 8 more
```

I found that if I manually remove the lib/netty-3.2.5.Final.jar file from the war before deploying it to JBOSS the problem goes away.

Now is there a way to do this when I'm generating the war with the play war command?
Any information on this would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I am aware of simply. The `play war` command allows you to pass an exclude list, which I have copied the comments from the python file below.

```
~ To exclude some directories, use the --exclude option and ':'-separator (eg: --exclude .svn:target:logs:tmp).
```

However, this suggests it will only work for directories.

The command that is executed is package_as_war in `framework/pym/utils.py`, so you can hack that to specifically delete the file, but obviously this will not be backward compatible if you update your version of Play.