# Play! Framework JBoss AS 7 deployment, how to initialize the database?

Tags: playframework, jboss7.x

I'm trying to deploy a Play 1.2.4 application to a JBoss 7.0.2 server (I am not allowed to use Play embedded server).

I already run into the following issues:

- jetty must be removed (see [Play! war command - Is it possible to exclude certain jar from the application /lib folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749255/play-war-command-is-it-possible-to-exclude-certain-jar-from-the-application)), solved removing the jar
- a `getSomething` function would trigger a [java.lang.VerifyError: Inconsistent stackmap frames](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987-play-framework/tickets/1234), for the moment solved removing the offending method - NB. for me it does happen only in JBoss, not in play-server mode

Now I'm trying to understand what's the pattern to initialize the database.

What's the best way? Should I set `jpa.ddl=update` then comment it back again, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either leave it to update or manage your database changes with [evolutions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/evolutions).

Evolutions tend to give you finer control over the schema changes and is many prefer it for production environment.

Comment: Personally I'm not a big fan of automatic ORM DDL generation, so I would prefer evolutions as well. Especially on a production environment, I prefer to deploy in 2 distinct steps: (1) update the database followed by (2) deploy the new version.

Comment: I do prefer evolutions in production too, and in any case explicit over transparent database modifications. What I'm slightly confused at is how to bootstrap the database. Sounds weird that I have to edit `application.conf` twice for it...

Answer (score 1):

In the meanwhile I found on the lighthouse play bugtracking system that an [undocument jpa.ddl option](https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1378-documentation-jpaddlcreate-in-prod-mode#ticket-1378-2)

```
jpa.ddl = create
```

exists. <strike>It would modify the database only when it does not exists. Sensitive.</strike>

This sounds to me like a good default settings to start with, because usually when deploying the database is not there yet.

This answers *half* of my question.

Now I wonder if there's a way to get the migration kicks in *before* the database is created - or if `jpa.ddl=create` is as good as it gets.

### Edit

I must say I'm far from having found a satisfactory solution;

I haven't even exactly understood how ddl=create is supposed to works, and the lack of precise documentations is not likely to change.

So that's what I do now:

I keep my database in memory from a good part of the initial development, with `ddl=update`.
When I feel i'm relatively stable I move to a mysql database and start writing evolutions as suggested by @emt14.

I personally keep using the mem db to quickly go and grab the correct sql to write my own evolutions, and I have a few with different play IDs to switch from mem to file to real database so that I can keep my data persistent while quickly testing new code.

I used to write a lot of fixtures but I don't know of a way to easily turn them into evolutions (beside copying the generated sql!) so I might stop doing so.

I might one day try the [migrate module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/migrate)... but I'm actually more likely to move to Play 2.x before that happens. Too much traction is there to bother too much with the 1.2.x series beside maintaining existing projects.

All in all, I end up mostly using the two extremes (`ddl=update` with `mem db`, `ddl=none` with `mysql/pgsql` real database) and dumping by hand data from the mem:db to write my own evolutions including required initial fixtures (different from test data fixtures).

Answer (score 0):

For database changes, most project I have seen have proprietary solution - simply they check the schema and add columns and tables which are missing. Downgrading is usually not considered :)

Anyway - in case of structural changes, I would probably not let some tool fiddle with the data, and would rather rely on a DBA and testers to develop and test a bullet-proof migration script.

Comment: "simply they check the schema and add columns and tables which are missing"... how do you usually proceed to generate the first SQL file containing the table and the initial data (fixtures) ? I like that Play can do it itself... but how can I tell him /when/ to do it? The ""create"" option I mention in my answer is a good step forward, but I'm still missing something....